# change 'breaks' argument of hist() function with R

Tags: r, histogram

I want to do the following :

- Open a window (easy with tcl/tk)
- add "*breaks*" field, "*apply*" button, and "*accept*" button to the window (easy too)
- loop while i < nbFiles

  - read file i (easy)
  - display an histogram of the data in current file in the window (need help)
  - user can provide ***breaks*** argument of [hist() function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) in the field, and once he pushes *apply* button, new histogram with that configuration will be displayed in the window (need help)
  - wait for *accept* button to be pushed (Need help) >> histogram will be saved in a file (easy)
  - close the window (easy)

Is it possible ? can I do that with R and tcl tk ?
An idea ?
thanks

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes". To your second is "I don't  know". How about you give a try, show what you were able to do so far and then we discuss it?

Comment: I already did it, but that was ugly : read file, call hist function (histogram was plotted in a R device window), open a *yesno* window.. if yes, next file and repeat from beginning.. if no, open a window with field and OK button.. one user provided "breaks" in the field, and then pressed ok, the new histogram was plotted.. But I could not handle the "**wait for OK button to be pushed**", the window (with field and ok button) opened but my program still continue to the next file..

Comment: Why are you using `tcl/tk`? I think it is easier to do this using ggWidgets or shiny ( web option).

Comment: I'm installing gWidgets package and it looks there is one named "**gWidgetstcltk**". Which one is better ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, possible, with tcltk.. [This is what you need](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/228581.html)  ?

ciao

Answer (score 0):

tkrplot can do that too

```
histo <- tkrplot(tt, function()hist(data)
tkgrid(histo)
```